# How to parse date in elasticsearch 5.x and Filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, filebeat

I am using elasticsearch 5.x and Filebeat and want to know if there is a way of parsing date(timestamp) directly in filebeat (don't want to use logstash). I am using `json.keys_under_root: true` and it works great, but the problem is that timestamp (on us) is recognised as string. All of the other fields were automatically recognised as correct types only this one isn't. [image]

How can I map it as date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Filebeat with the ES [Ingest Node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) feature to parse your `timestamp` field and apply the value to the `@timestamp` field.

You would setup a simple pipeline in Elasticsearch that applies a [date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/date-processor.html) to incoming events.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline
{
  "description" : "parse timestamp and update @timestamp",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "date" : {
        "field" : "timestamp",
        "target_field" : "@timestamp"
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": "timestamp"
      }
    }
  ],
  "on_failure": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "error.message",
        "value": "{{ _ingest.on_failure_message }}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then in Filebeat [configure](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html#_pipeline_2) the elasticsearch output to push data to your new pipeline.

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
  pipeline: my-pipeline
```

Comment: This seems a very elegant solution, will try it and accept answer. I just wonder isn't it possible by modifying filebeat template?

Comment: It is possible to modify the index template to interpret the `timestamp` field as a [date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html), but this won't replace the `@timestamp` field with the new value. If you have other data using `@timestamp` you probably will want to be consistent.

Comment: What I have experienced is that to recognise field as a date you only have to put it in right format in log file (example: `"2017-05-17T06:07:51.658998+00:00"`) this is then parsed as date. But I googled a bit more and found out that there is no straight forward way to parse on us resolution my date just gets truncated (if you found one please let me know).

Comment: What you are saying totally make sense and I will probably replace @timestamp with my custom timestamp via pipeline. Thanks.